# How to further break down a column based on another column after grouping it?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the number of suicides that occurred from year 1985-2016. Which i did easily
by

```
df.groupby('year').suicides_no.sum()
```

Now i want to break down the total number of suicides happened per year further into male and female.
The column name is 'sex' which contains two values - male , female.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a further group (long format):

```
df.groupby(['year', 'sex'])['suicides_no'].sum()
```

Or use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) (wide format):

```
pd.crosstab(df['year'], df['sex'], values=df['suicides_no'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: I can't believe how simply the answer was. Thank you bro. I totally forgot that you can add multiple columns in groupby() function. I was adding the sex column with the suicides_no column insteading of adding it along with the year in the groupby().